# MapReduce queries are not executing on Hive?

Tags: ubuntu, hive, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop2

I am new to Hadoop & Hive, whenever I start executing Hive MapReduce queries such as SELECT COUNT(*), Avg(), or loading data in Hbase, etc. it show following error I googled it but no solution yet. 
Whereas other normal queries such as select *, create, use, are working well.

```
hive> select count(*) from test_table;
Query ID = dev4_20171016095209_43c4e980-efbd-42d3-94d4-1a4b8de3d956
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1508127394848_0001, Tracking URL = http://dev4:8088/proxy/application_1508127394848_0001/
Kill Command = /usr/local/hadoop-2.8.1//bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1508127394848_0001
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2017-10-16 09:52:38,820 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1508127394848_0001 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

hadoop - (mapred-site.xml)

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.job.map.memory.mb</name>
            <value>8192</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.job.reduce.memory.mb</name>
            <value>4096</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
            <value>4096</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
            <value>4096</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
            <value>-Xmx2048M</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hadoop - core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/home/dev4/local/hadoop-2.8.1/tmp/hadoop-${dev4}</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Hadoop - mapreduce-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386/

export HADOOP_JOB_HISTORYSERVER_HEAPSIZE=1000

export HADOOP_MAPRED_ROOT_LOGGER=INFO,RFA

export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
#export HADOOP_JOB_HISTORYSERVER_OPTS=
#export HADOOP_MAPRED_LOG_DIR="" # Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/logs by default.
#export HADOOP_JHS_LOGGER=INFO,RFA # Hadoop JobSummary logger.
#export HADOOP_MAPRED_PID_DIR= # The pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
#export HADOOP_MAPRED_IDENT_STRING= #A string representing this instance of hadoop. $USER by default
#export HADOOP_MAPRED_NICENESS= #The scheduling priority for daemons. Defaults to 0.
```

Hadoop - yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Hive - hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
        <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>hiveuser</value>
        <description>user name for connecting to mysql server</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>harileela</value>
        <description>password for connecting to mysql server</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
        <value>file:///usr/local/hive/lib/hive-serde-1.2.2.jar</value>
        <description>The location of the plugin jars that contain implementations of user defined functions and serdes.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer</name>
        <value>1000000</value>
     </property>

</configuration>
```

Here's my application overview:

```
User:   dev4
Name:   select count(*) from test_table(Stage-1)
Application Type:   MAPREDUCE
Application Tags:   
Application Priority:   0 (Higher Integer value indicates higher priority)
YarnApplicationState:   FAILED
Queue:  default
FinalStatus Reported by AM:     FAILED
Started:    Mon Oct 16 13:10:37 +0530 2017
Elapsed:    8sec
Tracking URL:   History
Log Aggregation Status:     DISABLED
Diagnostics:    
Application application_1508139045948_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1508139045948_0002_000002 exited with exitCode: 127
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001
Exit code: 127
Exception message: /bin/bash: /home/dev4/local/hadoop-2.8.1/tmp/hadoop-/nm-local-dir/usercache/dev4/appcache/application_1508139045948_0002/container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001/default_container_executor_session.sh: No such file or directory
/home/dev4/local/hadoop-2.8.1/tmp/hadoop-${dev4}/nm-local-dir/usercache/dev4/appcache/application_1508139045948_0002/container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001/default_container_executor.sh: line 4: /home/dev4/local/hadoop-2.8.1/tmp/hadoop-/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/application_1508139045948_0002/container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001/container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001.pid.exitcode.tmp: No such file or directory
/bin/mv: cannot stat '/home/dev4/local/hadoop-2.8.1/tmp/hadoop-/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/application_1508139045948_0002/container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001/container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001.pid.exitcode.tmp': No such file or directory
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=127: /bin/bash: /home/dev4/local/hadoop-2.8.1/tmp/hadoop-/nm-local-dir/usercache/dev4/appcache/application_1508139045948_0002/container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001/default_container_executor_session.sh: No such file or directory
/home/dev4/local/hadoop-2.8.1/tmp/hadoop-${dev4}/nm-local-dir/usercache/dev4/appcache/application_1508139045948_0002/container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001/default_container_executor.sh: line 4: /home/dev4/local/hadoop-2.8.1/tmp/hadoop-/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/application_1508139045948_0002/container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001/container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001.pid.exitcode.tmp: No such file or directory
/bin/mv: cannot stat '/home/dev4/local/hadoop-2.8.1/tmp/hadoop-/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/application_1508139045948_0002/container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001/container_1508139045948_0002_02_000001.pid.exitcode.tmp': No such file or directory
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:236)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:84)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://dev4:8088/cluster/app/application_1508139045948_0002 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
Unmanaged Application:  false
Application Node Label expression:  <Not set>
AM container Node Label expression:     <DEFAULT_PARTITION>
```

I  don't know where is the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Nobody can know what the problem is. Because you are not providing any useful information. There are already hundreds of questions like this one  on S.O. and the answer is always _"inspect  the YARN logs to understand why the return code of the YARN container was non-zero"_.

Comment: Hey Samson thanks for reply, I added the logs detail (as application overview) and went through it but still I can't get out.

Comment: check the actual log so you can get the real error. ("/tmp/hive.log")

Comment: `For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://dev4:8088/cluster/app/application_1508139045948_0002 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.` These "logs of each attempt" are the YARN logs I was talking about.